# Legend for two parametric surfaces

Tags: plotting, legending

I have the plot of two surfaces given by

```
 pN          = ParametricPlot3D[{0,u,v},{u,-0.25,0.25},{v,-0.5,0.5},\
               Mesh->None,PlotStyle->Directive[Gray,Opacity[0.4]]
               ];
 pS          = ParametricPlot3D[{u,v^2,v},{u,-0.25,0.25},{v,-0.5,0.5},\
               Mesh->None,PlotStyle->Directive[Green,Opacity[0.4]]
               ];
```

Then, I combine the two surfaces on the same plot with

```
  Show[pN,pS]
```

and I can export my figure.

I would like to create a text legend (or a automatic text label) for these two surfaces (maybe a color designation would be easier to begin with).

I tried :

```
 pN          = Legended[\
                 ParametricPlot3D[{0,u,v},{u,-0.25,0.25},{v,-0.5,0.5}]\
               ,"My Text for Surface N"]
```

but we can't determine what surface this piece of text refers to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ParametricPlot3D[{{0, u, v}, {u, v^2, v}}, {u, -0.25, 0.25}, {v, -0.5, 0.5},
Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> {Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.4]],
Directive[Green, Opacity[0.4]]}, 
PlotLegends -> 
SwatchLegend[{Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.4]], 
Directive[Green, Opacity[0.4]]}, {"pN", "pS"}]]
```

[image]

To add different meshes it is better have separate plots and then combine them:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{0, u, v}, {u, -0.25, 0.25}, {v, -0.5, 0.5}, 
Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> {Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.4]]}, 
PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[{Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.4]]}, {"pN"}]]

ParametricPlot3D[{u, v^2, v}, {u, -0.25, 0.25}, {v, -0.5, 0.5}, 
Mesh -> 5, PlotStyle -> {Directive[Green, Opacity[0.4]]}, 
PlotLegends -> 
SwatchLegend[{Directive[Green, Opacity[0.4]]}, {"pS"}]]

Show[%,%%]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, what is I would like to customize the mesh style for eaach surface: 
for the green, I would like Mesh=None and for the blue I would like Mesh=5.
Mesh -> {None,5} doesn't seem to work.

Or if I would like to add a RegionFunction, how can I specify different function for each surface ?

Comment: I edited answer to have different meshes. Thanks for accepting!

Answer (score 3):

```
 ParametricPlot3D[{{0, u, v}, {u, v^2, v}}, {u, -0.25, 0.25}, {v, -0.5, 0.5}, 
    MeshFunctions -> {# &, #3 Boole[# != 0] &}, 
    Mesh -> 5, 
    PlotStyle -> (Opacity[0.4, #] & /@ {Gray, Green}), 
    PlotLegends -> {"pN", "pS"}]
```

[image]